# Random numbers and uppercase result instead of a number ->

Tags: python

I'm working on this calculator but the output that I keep getting is function ops at 0x03B0B858 instead of it being a number, and i'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong....

The calculator asks three questions, first number, operator, and the second number. if you type in letters or anything other than numbers when asked the first number and the second number, it will tell you that what you typed in was invalid and asks you to enter a valid number again, the problem is that I'm trying to do that with the operator as well which is defined inside the function ops() but it doesn't matter what I typed in the operator the result will always be random letters and numbers.... This is the code below, you can copy past it and try it and see what I mean by all of this..

```
try:
  num1 = float(input('Enter the first number: '))
except ValueError:
  print('Invalid number')
  num1 = float(input('Enter first number again: '))

op = input('Enter operator: ')

try:
  num2 = float(input('Enter the second number: '))
except ValueError:
  print('Invalid number')
  num2 = float(input('Enter second number again: '))

def ops():
  if op != '+' or '-' or '/' or '*':
    op = input('Invalid Operator, please enter operator: ')

  elif op == '+':
    return num1 + num2
  elif op == '-':
    return num1 - num2
  elif op == '*':
    return num1 * num2
  elif op == '/':
    return num1 / num2


print(ops)
```

Comment: You're not *calling* the function.

Comment: to add on to what @jonrsharpe is saying, you need to call ops by doing `ops()`.  You probably want to do `print(ops())` instead of `print(ops)` at the end.  (`ops` is a function, so when you print it, python tries to print an "ID" of the function)

Comment: U can trying using type(op). This return int or string if(type(op) == Int ) continue..

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not? How?

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*? By... not calling it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I am, i'm using the print(ops) to run the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wait should it be print(ops(num1, num2))?

Comment: That *doesn't* run the function, it *prints* it. And no, because ops doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: You call a function with ()'s. By saying `print(ops)`, you are only printing the handle to the function. You should instead do `print(ops())`.

Comment: @RaniFaris: Please work through a tutorial on function usage.  This is not how you call a function.  You asked Python to print out some representation of the function definition.

Comment: Also, at the very top of your file I see you're trying to do some error catching. But what if I, as the user, enter in an invalid input twice? The first time will send me to the except ValueError block, and the second time will raise ValueError because you don't even try to catch it. You should probably use a While loop and only break out of it if the user enters valid input or some kind of escape sequence you define

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Yes you're right I've just noticed that, but assuming that we entered valid numbers and I called the function with print(ops()), I still get an error, it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'op' referenced before assignment

Comment: You are mixing global and local namespaces. The global namespace is everything that isn't in a function or a class basically. The local namespace is local to whatever function or class you are in. In your code, op, num1, and num2 are defined in the global namespace (you can see your globals by doing `print(globals())`).  When you move to the function's local namespace, it has no idea what the global variables are. So what should you do?--Move everything inside of your `ops` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

First: 
- to run the function 'ops' you should call `print(ops())` , do not forget the parentheses 
- try putting the code inside the function, otherwise, your function won't recognize the variable 'op' 
- you cannot check the content of the variable 'op' like that

```
op != '+' or '-' or '/' or '*'
```

this will be evaluated as a single boolean 'OR',
 
your code should go like that instead:

```
if op not in ['+' , '-' , '/' , '*']:
   do smthg...
```

Edit 2: 
 
Complete solution:

```
def ops():
    try:
        num1 = float(input('Enter the first number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number')
        num1 = float(input('Enter first number again: '))

    op = input('Enter operator:')
    try:
        num2 = float(input('Enter the second number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number')
        num2 = float(input('Enter second number again: '))

    if op not in ['+' , '-' , '/' , '*']:
        op = input('Invalid Operator, please enter operator: ')
    if op == '+':
        return num1 + num2
    elif op == '-':
        return num1 - num2
    elif op == '*':
        return num1 * num2
    elif op == '/':
        return num1 / num2

print(ops())
```

Comment: Still, if I put something invalid in the operator I will be asked to enter a valid input and when I do the result would be none.

Comment: replace the "elif"  with a normal "if" (like the last edit)